# serving user content/images from amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture

I am building an app which lets users upload pictures and share it with his/her friends only.

1. I am using spring restful services to upload content directly to s3.
2. The user is authorized using OAuth.
3. To upload an image an authorized user's js client invokes POST /images/{userid}
4. To download the image, the client has to invoke GET /images/{userid}/{imageid}

Each user's content is stored in s3 under his own folder name, and the downloading service as explained in point 4 is the one that has to be invoked. Unfortunately, this means I cannot assign this url as source to an image tag `<img src="">`, because the authorization token should be sent on GET request. I cannot make the contents of user folder public because only user and his friends are allowed to see the images. The current service will soon become a bottleneck and I would like to avoid that.

What is the recommended architecture/design to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a service that loads and returns the entire image file from S3, you should have a service that simply generates an S3 presigned URL. Then the URL retrieved from that service can be used in the `<img src="">` tags on your site. This will be much more performant since the web browser will ultimately download the image directly from S3, while also still being secure.

Comment: so, pre-signed url creation should be a batch job? I mean say userA uploads his private images, so I create presigned urls, when his friends want to see his private images, the presigned urls are used, but what about expiry? if presigned urls expire, then do I have a batch job regenerate the presigned urls again for all images uploaded by userA?

Comment: No, presigned URLs expire after a period of time. You would generate them as needed, when someone is loading a page that includes the images.

Answer (score 1):

The flow for downloading the images would be like this

User invokes GET request to download image

- At Server End

  - Authenticate user
  - Query DB for metadata
  - Create a time based auth token.
  - Create a image URL(S3 based) and append auth token created in previous step
- At the client end(User browser) redirect user to new URL(this url is effectively S3 location+auth token )
- Now direct request will comes at the server( image URL+ auth token)

  - authenticate the token and then show image to user

Above URL will not be valid for long time , but your images are secured. As auth token is time based it will cater your case like if some one make the image private/public remove a friend.Deleted images , Copy paste of image url etc ..

Comment: ok.. what your suggesting still involves using tokens - this is a problem if I have to use src attribute of "img" tag.

Comment: use parameter to pass auth token in "img tag". At server end apply filter on URL regex , authenticate token and then stream image in response out.